# Unstable folding with tex files due to Vimwiki editing + saving

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, tex

I am using [Vimwiki](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki) and LaTeX (Using [Vim-Latex-Suite](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) actively. Here goes one weird observation:

After having specified `setlocal nofoldenable` in the `tex.vim` file stored in `~\ftplugin` dir, I got rid of folding for latex files; Same `setlocal` command had been also specifiecd in the `vimwiki.vim` file.

However, if I do the following, I will end up with a continuously folded tex file:

(Note, setting `set nofoldenable` in the `ftplugin\*.vim` file at the end of such file does not help; moving theses setting to the end of `_vimrc` also did not help to disable the folding problem.)

1. Open `*.tex` file;
2. Edit and save a `*.wiki` file (the `filetype` changed to be `vimwiki` when editing and saving);
3. Open a new GVim.exe session and open the `*.tex` file.
4. It turns out that:

   1) All the sections and all subsidiary structures (subsection, subsubsection, paragraph, subparagraph, etc..) shall have been folded;

   2) Save and exiting and restarting Gvim session will give the same folded structure, regardless of whether foldings were opened/deleted or not;

   3) Writing such file onto a fresh location will not contain any folding as long as no `*.wiki` file is saved using the same Gvim session.

   4) Editing and saving a `*.wiki` file in the same Gvim session will send the newly saved file back to the state with persistent folding structure.

I am not sure if my including the [vim-scripts/restore_view](https://github.com/vim-scripts/restore_view.vim) plugin should have lead to all these masses.

I also notice that, the pollution towards the `*.tex` file is **file-name specific**! (or *absolute-path specific*.) It does not help if I replace the folded `*.tex` file with its exact copy from a clean directory, the persistent folding remains. Only when I rename the file in the same directory will solve the folding issue.

As of now, I can only restrain myself from editing a `*.wiki` file when writing on a `*.tex` file. Or, rename the `*.tex` file after having commit the crime of "editing a `*.wiki` file while in a Tex-Gvim session".

Any thoughts on stabilizing the folding, or saving a set of manual folding will also be very helpful!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try unsettings folds in viewoptions. Once you unfold a loaded *.tex file, run below command inside vim and then save your file as wiki.

```
:set viewoptions-=folds
```

I don't have a windows system at hands, hence could not try it myself before suggesting. Sorry! :(

Comment: Nice and clean! I added `setlocal viewoptions-=folds` to `~\ftplugin\tex.vim`, which implementes filetype-specific settings. Thanks a lot!