# folding settings in vimrc not working in vimwiki

Tags: vim

I want to activate folding by identation in vimwiki

my .vimrc looks like that:

```
set foldmethod=indent
set foldnestmax=10
set foldlevel=1
set shiftwidth=4
set foldcolumn=1
```

This works as intended in a normal vim file. However, in vimwiki it does not work. Do I have to set up any additional variable in my vimrc file?

Already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33601872/unstable-folding-with-tex-files-due-to-vimwiki-editing-saving) similar post and it solve this problem.

*'vimwiki' tag doesn't exist yet and due to my rep. I can't create it :(*

Comment: Indirect cross-site dupe of https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2370/vimwiki-cant-fold-list-items

Comment: I have to start looking in the stackexchange. thanks. In the meantime, i found this solution in their github issues, too: https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/issues/567